# Apache Vhosts only working locally

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

Ok, I have added lines like:

```
127.0.0.1   somedomain.com
```

Or some other domain that points to my routers IP, and is forwarded, but I get to the main site, but I want it to go to the subfolder I defined in my httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost  somedomain.com:80

<VirtualHost somedomain.com:80>
 DocumentRoot "D:/Apps/xampp/htdocs/somedomain"
 ServerName somedomain.com
 ServerAlias somedomain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

So, locally somedomain.com works, just remotely it goes to the root htdocs. So If I use a *:80 wildcard I works, but then everything points to the subfolder and all the other vhosts seem to get ignored.

Any Idea why this is?

Answer (score 3):

1. DO NOT, ever, use hostnames in a VirtualHost definition. Use IP:80 or *:80.
2. *Domains* are not "forwarded" - traffic is.
   What you put in your local hosts file has nothing to do with how remote traffic gets routed to your web server.

As always, the ServerName is decisive; the Host: header is compared with the ServerName, and if a matching vhost is found, that is who receives the request.

Comment: 1. But then what IP do i put after NameVirtualHost? Just 127.0.0.1?

Comment: 2. So like I have it now it is OK? behind the ServerName?

Comment: You have that name resolving to localhost, so it's only attached to localhost traffic (why are you using the hosts file, by the way?).  Change your vhost directives:  `NameVirtualHost *:80` and `<VirtualHost *:80>`.

Comment: Thing is, i want bla.bla.com to go to my root (it points to my modem/router), so I have it pointed to /htdocs, and the other, somedomain.com (also pointing to my router IP) I want to point to /somedomain....

Comment: How is that related to how vhosts should be set up ?

Comment: Ok, turns out I want using the httpd-vhosts.conf file in the extra folder, which is not loaded at all, so I was messing around with the hosts file at the same time, while it was all so simple...